# MySQL timestamp SELECT

Tags: mysql

I have a column in my table that is called timestamp that is in this format: 2012-05-01 15:33:06

How do I perform a select that only pulls records within the last 15 min?  I found this in the PHP manual but am not sure how to modify for 15 minutes?  Can someone give me a sample?

> WHERE timestamp(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 30 DAY)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using [timestampdiff](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff)

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,`yourcolumn`,CURDATE()) = 15;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this............

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
WHERE COLUMN_NAME >= NOW() - INTERVAL 15 MINUTE
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT .. FROM <table_name> Where <field_name> >= (DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE))
```

Answer (score 1):

My logic tells me that I should try **MINUTE** instead of **DAY**.. did you tried it?

```
WHERE timestamp(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 15 MINUTE)
```